# Tengo problemas cuando quiero mostrar en un TextView la informacion de un ArrayList

Tags: android-studio, arraylist, textview

Soy nuevo en esto de la programacion en Android y me encuentro que quiero acceder a la informacion de un ArrayList que recupero mediante Volley de un webservice y me da el siguiente error cuando quiero asignar el valor del Array a un TextView (tx1.setText(articulos.get(0).getCodigo().toString());)

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplicationprueba1, PID: 344
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplicationprueba1/com.example.myapplicationprueba1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplicationprueba1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

El MainActivity es el siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Articulo> articulos;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TextView tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    cargarDatosDesdeWebService();
    tx1.setText(articulos.get(0).getCodigo().toString());

}

public void cargarDatosDesdeWebService(){

    Response.Listener<String> rtaArticulosPedidos = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response1) {

            try {

                JSONObject JsonRespuesta = new JSONObject(response1);
                boolean ok = JsonRespuesta.getBoolean("success");
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                jsonArray = JsonRespuesta.getJSONArray("articulos");
                if (ok == true) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                        articulos.add(new Articulo(jsonObject.getString("codigoArt"), jsonObject.getString("descripcion"),
                                jsonObject.getString("sinonimo"), jsonObject.getInt("cantidad"),
                                jsonObject.getString("posicionSAP"), jsonObject.getString("posicionDEP")));

                    }
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    alerta.setMessage("Error").setNegativeButton("Reintentar", null).create().show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }

    };
    ArticulosRequest rArt = new ArticulosRequest(" 000100019723", rtaArticulosPedidos);
    RequestQueue cola = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    cola.add(rArt);
}
```

}

La clase Articulo es la siguiente:

```
public class Articulo {

private String codigo;
private String descripcion;
private String sinonimo;
private int cantidad;
private String SAP;
private String DEP;


public Articulo(String codigo, String descripcion, String sinonimo, int cantidad, String SAP, String DEP) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.sinonimo = sinonimo;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    this.SAP = SAP;
    this.DEP = DEP;
}

public String getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String getSinonimo() {
    return sinonimo;
}

public void setSinonimo(String sinonimo) {
    this.sinonimo = sinonimo;
}

public int getCantidad() {
    return cantidad;
}

public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}

public String getSAP() {
    return SAP;
}

public void setSAP(String SAP) {
    this.SAP = SAP;
}

public String getDEP() {
    return DEP;
}

public void setDEP(String DEP) {
    this.DEP = DEP;
}
```

}

La clase ArticulosRequest es la siguiente:

```
public class ArticulosRequest extends StringRequest {

   private  static final String ruta = "http://192.168.0.186:80/SAP/App3/buscaArticulosPedido.php";
    private Map<String, String> parametros;

    public ArticulosRequest(String nroPedido, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, ruta, listener, null);
        parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("NroPedido", nroPedido+"");
        // parametros.put("Clave", Clave+"");
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
        return parametros;
    }
```

}

y el XML es el siguiente:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="309dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="228dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Probar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan ofrecer!!

Comment: Parece que `jsonObject` es nulo. Imprime en el Log la respuesta que recibes de Volley (`response1`) y muéstrala en la pregunta para saber cómo poder ayudarte mejor. Sin ver la estructura del JSON es imposible poder saber cómo hay que leerlo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta A. Cedano. Ya creo haber encontrado el problema pero tampoco se como solucionarlo. El problema creo que esta en que cuando lleno el arrayList con los datos q necesito dentro del onResponse luego cuando intento acceder a ese arrayList desde otro procedimiento es donde me tira el error. Tiene que ser un tema de alcance de variables o forma de declararla ya que desde ese metodo onResponse si puedo acceder a los datos del arreglo. Nose si fui claro como para que me puedas ayudar.

Comment: Entiendo. Si quieres usar el arraylist fuera del `onResponse`
 tienes dos opciones: 1. Lo declaras como miembro de la clase, por lo general sería `private` o 2. Lo pasas en parámetro al otro método donde quieres usarlo.